Why can't I log into duolingo-api in python with duolingo.Duolingo('username', 'password')?
I'm trying to access my duolingo data via scripting, and found duolingo-api.
https://pypi.org/project/duolingo-api/
https://github.com/KartikTalwar/Duolingo
I followed their installtion and usage directions in the documentation, but consistently get the same error when trying to log in.
This post seemed promising, but I couldn't figure out how to apply it to my case.
Login into Duolingo using Python Requests
install via bash:
$ pip install duolingo-api
python script:
import duolingo
lingo  = duolingo.Duolingo('kartik', 'my password')

the error:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/"<my-current-directory>"/duolingo/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 974, in json
    return complexjson.loads(self.text, **kwargs)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/json/__init__.py", line 346, in loads
    return _default_decoder.decode(s)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/json/decoder.py", line 337, in decode
    obj, end = self.raw_decode(s, idx=_w(s, 0).end())
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib64/python3.11/json/decoder.py", line 355, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/"<my-current-directory>"/duolingo/tmp.py", line 2, in <module>
    lingo  = duolingo.Duolingo('usrname','password')
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/"<my-current-directory>"/duolingo/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/duolingo.py", line 66, in __init__
    self._login()
  File "/home/"<my-current-directory>"/duolingo/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/duolingo.py", line 105, in _login
    attempt = request.json()
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/"<my-current-directory>"/duolingo/lib64/python3.11/site-packages/requests/models.py", line 978, in json
    raise RequestsJSONDecodeError(e.msg, e.doc, e.pos)
requests.exceptions.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

I tried analyzing the error and the source code, but being new to python and web requests, I couldn't make sense of it.
I have also tried installing globally, and in a virtual environment, on a slackware, arch and 2 windows machines with the same result.
I can't find any information on this package online other than its own documentation, and can't figure out what to do.
Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

After a shallow study of the duolingo-api package you are using, it seems it is just way out of date. It uses internally the  link "https://www.duolingo.com/login" to login, which is no longer used by the website, and the package hasn't received any update for the past 3 years, so my guess is just that this particular library is not usable anymore.
